# vcenter - has zero length, and can't possibly store a file system or partition table. Perhaps you selected the wrong device?

Tags: esxi

I am trying to create a vmfs file sysetm on my 3TB USB storage following the tutorial on:

http://www.virten.net/2015/10/usb-devices-as-vmfs-datastore-in-vsphere-esxi-6-0/

However, on step 6, Write a GPT label to the device, I am seeing the following error:

partedUtil mklabel "/dev/disks/mpx.vmhba49:C0:T0:L0" gpt
Error: The device /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba49:C0:T0:L0 has zero length, and can't possibly store a file system or partition table.  Perhaps you selected the wrong device?
Unable to get device /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba49:C0:T0:L0

I also tried to partition the 3TB into 1.8T and 1.2T
With FAT32 and EXT3(not recognized) respectively but I am still seeing the same issue.

I am wondering why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard drive controller on your USB dock is probably not supported or on the VMware Hardware compatibly list.  Try a different dock, but keep your receipt if that doesn't work either.